# Python PaaS with local socket

Tags: python, sockets, paas

This could be a dumb question... but are there any PaaS platforms that would allow me to host python code which could control my *local* app via sockets?

We automate a lot of application tasks via python, but ideally we'd like to host the code.

Comment: Are you thinking in terms of your local code connecting outwards to your PaaS platform (eg. the PaaS is running a server) and then receiving commands down the connection it initiated?  Or in terms of your PaaS server initiating connections back to your local code?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org) Open Source PaaS stack allows you to run whatever code you want. So as part of your Cloudify 'recipe' you can install python and run your code. Cloudify will handle the provisioning of machines, logging, etc.

You can run Cloudify in one of the supported clouds, or using your local available machines using the Bring-Your-Own-Node cloud driver: http://www.cloudifysource.org/guide/2.2/setup/configuring_byon.html.

Disclaimer: I work for GigaSpaces, developer of the [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org) open-source PaaS stack.